# Необходима помощь с Django 2.1

Tags: django

```html
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,
                      self).get_queryset()\
                        .filter(status='published')


class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICE = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published')
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICE,
                              default='published')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog_site:post_detail',
                       args=[self.publish.year,
                             self.publish.month,
                             self.publish.day,
                             self.slug])
```

```html
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                             status='published',
                             publish__year=year,
                             publish__month=month,
                             publish__day=day)

    # List of active comment fot this post
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)

    new_comment = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # A comment was posted
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            # Create Comment object bot don't save to database yet
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            # Assign the current post to the new comment
            new_comment.post = post
            # Save the comment to the database
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    return render(request,
                  'blog_site/post/detail.html',
                  {'post': post,
                   'comments': comments,
                   'new_comment': new_comment,
                   'comment_form': comment_form})
```

```html
Template error:
In template Z:\Django\blog\blog_site\templates\blog_site\base.html, error at line 0
   Manager isn't accessible via Post instances
   1 : {% load static %}
   2 : 
   3 : <html>
   4 : <head>
   5 :     <meta charset="UTF-8">
   6 :     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   7 :     <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
   8 :     <link href="{% static "css/blog_site.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
   9 : </head>
```

Когда вызывается функция post_detail(), чтобы перейти к подробному описанию поста, выходит ошибка template. Не понимаю, что означает эта ошибка. Был бы благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Где-то в коде у вас вместо обращения к менеджеру класса используется попытка обращения к менеджеру объекта - `post.objects` вместо `Post.objects.` или что-то вроде этого.

Comment: Что интересно, в Traceback-е он показывает ошибку в коде html в нулевой строке, хотя там, насколько я понимаю нет обращений к объектам класса

Comment: @Molex шаблонизатор не всегда может определить место возникновение ошибки.